# Display a text message on macOS Desktop background

Tags: desktop, wallpaper

I would like to display a message, for example, the OS Version, the installed tool versions etc on the Desktop background of macOS.

I understand that the lockscreen text can be edited, I am not talking about that. That is not what I am interested in.

I know there is a way because I have seen my colleagues at my previous job do this.

NOTE: I want to do this from command line.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible using [NerdTool](http://mutablecode.com/apps/nerdtool.html) or [GeekTool](https://www.tynsoe.org/v2/geektool/). You can create custom ones writing command line codes or display content from logs.[image]

Find inspiration for code from [here](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/geeklets/) and mac AppStorm made a great article with lots of [crazy geeklets](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/over-46-powerful-geeklets-and-scripts-for-the-geek-within-you/) .

Comment: Sadly nerdtool appears to not be live anymore (github links are 404)

Comment: @JordanKasper Geektool still works. Link - www.tynsoe.org/v2/geektool/

Comment: I instead resorted to using imagemagick to annotate the a jpeg and used it as a wallpaper. I love this way because I can periodically update the wallpaper with whatever message I want from my script